# Fetch Billing Details for my O365 subscription through APIS (I do not have Azure subscription) #Office 365

Tags: office365, o365-flow

I wanted to fetch the details of the licenses, billing details of my O365 subscription through APIs.
Is there any such API available? I want to fetch the details available on this page for example

https://admin.microsoft.com/Adminportal/Home?source=applauncher&ref=/users#/licenses

#office365

Comment: I've searched, and Microsoft is VERY intentional about not even putting prices in a grid view in the M365 admin site. True billing data is only provided via e-mailed monthly invoice PDFs - you'd have to parse that data and use it for actual costs, unfortunately.

The MS Graph API does have a subscribedSku entity which gives details on which products your org is subscribed to, including # of consumed license units. If you could find or build a price sheet, you could get cost estimates for monthly licenses. Consumption-based SKUs like Communications Credits may require a different solution.